# Regular representation

Tags: representation-theory

This is indeed a very simple question in representation theory, but I can not see why the Regular representation of a group G, satisfies the requirement of being a homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group, Let $R$ be the vector space of all complex-valued functions on $G$, then a given element $g \in G$ acts on $\alpha \in R$ by the following rule $$(g\alpha)(h)=\alpha(g^{-1}h) \ \ \ \ \ \forall h \in G$$
to prove that it is actually a representation, given $g_1,g_2 \in G$ we must have $$(g_1g_2 \alpha)(h)=(g_1 \alpha)(h) . (g_2 \alpha)(h) \ \ \ (*)$$ But $$(g_1g_2 \alpha)(h)= \alpha(g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}h) $$ and $$(g_1 \alpha)(h) . (g_2 \alpha)(h)=\alpha(g_1^{-1}h)\alpha(g_2^{-1}h)$$ I don't see why (*) holds, I'd appreciate your help in advance

Comment: Remember that $\alpha=\alpha(h)$, i.e., $\alpha$ is a function of $h$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula (*) is not correct.

What you have to check is that $(g_1 g_2)\alpha = g_1 (g_2 \alpha).$
Your formula (*) says something quite different.  (It involves multiplication
of functions, which has nothing to do with being a representation; typically
representations occur on vector spaces where multiplication wouldn't even
make sense.)